# Как корректно отобразить текстовые символы в консоли c#

Tags: c#

Допустим есть символ ☭, как его можно корректно вывести в консоли при помощи c#? Сейчас он отображается как знак вопроса.

Comment: Установите подходящие шрифт с поддержкой этого символа и убедитесь, что консоль использует кодировку UTF-8. Вообще говоря, эта проблема не относится к C#.

Comment: C# тут вообще ни при чем, нужно включить для использования в консоли юникодовового шрифта, что потребует шаманств с редактированием реестра, админ прав и прочих перезагрузок. На машине клиента это может быть невозможно по сотне причин. Поэтому я рекомендую вам отказаться от этой затеи. Если уж нужна "графика" - используйте GUI. Кстати сделать окошко похожее на консоль но с использованием юникода, например, на WPF не составит большого труда (наверное, в зависимости от ваших нужд)

Comment: @Андрей, ну не надо всех под одну гребёнку грести. Вот у меня в ОС по умолчанию используется юникод для вывода в терминал. И такой символ спокойно печатается с помощью `System.Console.WriteLine("☭")`.

Comment: @mymedia, а у меня нет, например, и? Вы предлагаете мне запустить программу, которая потребует админ прав, полезет мне в реестр и начнет ломать отображение в консоли? Для домашних экспериментов, может и нормально, но не более...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Проверьте, что свойство [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding) установлено в `Encoding.UTF8`.
2. Установите в свойства консоли шрифт, поддерживающий символы Юникод.

Comment: andreycha, а как это проверить? Написал ```OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8```, но такого класса как Encoding не существует

Comment: Не надо задавать вопросы в поле для ответов. `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`