# C# В массиве int хранятся коды символов (win1251). Как мне вывести на экран сами символы?

Tags: c#, cp1251

При выводе на экран вместо текста знаки вопроса и иные символы, хотя на промежуточном выводе коды символов правильные. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
Console.Write("Введите код: ");
        string code = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] code1 = code.ToCharArray();

        Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(text);
        int[] text1 = new int[text.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) text1[i] = bytes[i];


        int[] text2 = new int[text.Length];
        int b = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < text.Length; a++)
        {
            if (bytes[a] >= 65 && bytes[a] <= 95
                || bytes[a] >= 97 && bytes[a] <= 122
                || bytes[a] >= 192 && bytes[a] <= 255
                || bytes[a] == 168 || bytes[a] == 184
                || bytes[a] >= 48 && bytes[a] <= 57)
            {
                if (b < code.Length)
                {
                    text2[a] = text1[a] + Convert.ToInt32(code1[b].ToString());
                    b++;
                }
                else
                {
                    b = 0;
                    text2[a] = text1[a] + Convert.ToInt32(code1[b].ToString());
                    b++;
                }
                Console.Write(text2[a] + " ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < text2.Length; i++) Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(text2[i]));
        Console.WriteLine();
```

[image: программа]

Comment: [Раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703483/220553), [Два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450613/220553). Только кодировку естественно свою (`Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)`).

Comment: Покажите, как в этот массив попали эти символы.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом преобразования класса `Encoding`: `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetChars(bytesArray)`. Учтите, что на вход он принимает массив байт. Соответственно, ваш `int[]`нужно преобразовать в `byte[]`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, добавила в вопрос программу, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Vlad, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно int[] преобразовать в byte[]. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @АлинаТерещенко, Например, `var bytesArray = intArray.Select(_ => (byte)_).ToArray()`. При условии, конечно, что элементы массива int не больше 255. У Вас что-то загадочное в коде творится. Зачем нужен массив `text1`? Почему бы `text2` не сделать массивом байт? Зачем преобразовывать символ в строку, а потом в число? Думаю, на эти вопросы Вам лучше ответить прежде всего себе.

Answer (score 1):

Строки в дотнете юникодные. А именно, UTF-16. Символы, соответственно, тоже.

Типы `string` и `char` платформа .NET работают *только* с юникодом и никакие другие кодировки использовать *не могут*.

Вот здесь вы правильно получаете *байтовый массив*, содержащий текст в кодировке win1251, с помощью класса `Encoding`:

```
string text = "как дела";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(text);
```

После того, как вы поработали с байтами в нужной вам кодировке, нужно обратно преобразовать их в юникод.

Метод `Convert.ToChar` выдаст именно юникодный символ. Но он считает, что на вход получил *юникодный* код этого символа. А у вас код *win1251*.

Следовательно, нужно снова воспользоваться классом `Encoding`:

```
var byteArray = Array.ConvertAll(text2, n => (byte)n);
var result = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(byteArray);
```

Обратите внимание, что он принимает массив *байтов*, так что сперва нужно конвертировать ваш интовый массив.